# Fastest tool to calculate Pi (3.14…) from a given digit on Linux

Tags: gratis, linux, open-source, math, command-line

I want to calculate [Pi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pi) digits from 13 trillion to 13.1 trillion.

What is the fastest tool for this?

Requirements:

- Runs on Linux
- Open source
- Does NOT calculate the first 13 trillions (only calculates from the given offset)
- Output text file(s)

Answer (score 1):

You can computing the nth binary digit of pi using the [Plouffe formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bailey%E2%80%93Borwein%E2%80%93Plouffe_formula):

[image]

> The algorithm is the fastest way to compute the nth digit (or a few digits in a neighborhood of the nth); because of this, by using multiple machines, it is the fastest way to compute all the digits from 1 to n. Also, on a single machine If the memory size of all the digits from 1 – n causes thrashing on the machine, it is the fastest way to compute all the digits from 1 to n.

In [Python](http://jdb.github.io/faster.html):

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal as d, getcontext
>>> def bbp(n):
...    return sum( 1/d(16**k)                                      \
...                * (4/d(8*k+1)-2/d(8*k+4)-1/d(8*k+5)-1/d(8*k+6)) \
...                for k in xrange(n))
...
>>> print bbp(50)
3.141592653589793238462643381
>>>
>>> getcontext().prec = 70
>>> print bbp(50)
3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375105820974944592246655
```

As a result, it seems like you are looking for the fastest implementation of the Plouffe formula. I haven't seen any benchmark and it depends on your hardware (especially [GPU](http://on-demand.gputechconf.com/gtc/2013/presentations/S3071-Computing-the-Quadrillionth-Digit-of-Pi.pdf)).

Comment: Thanks! Could you please modify the Python code to calculate the digits from 13 trillion to 13 trillion + 10? For now bbp only takes one argument which means no offset.

Comment: @NicolasRaoul The formula as stated calculates Pi and not the nth digit of pi. Also, from Wikipedia I read that it calculates the *binary* digit, which is not a base 10 digit. How many binary digits do we need to calculate a numeric digit? And how to know which binary digits are needed?

Comment: Like in 0x0100: this is only 1 binary digit, but it affects 3 decimal digits: 2, 5 and 6